# AngularJS - how to convert &#39; in JSON to single quote

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am using the Stack Overflow API in an angularJS app and some of the titles contain `&#39;` instead of the single quote icon `'`

E.g:

```
title: "Can&#39;t bind to &#39;ngModel&#39; since it isn&#39;t a known property of &#39;input&#39;"
```

How can I convert this before pulling it into an ng-repeat?

I've had a look around but unfortunately none of the answers are working for me. I've tried a `.replace` in the `{{question.title}}` and also a method within the controller.

```
var loadFeed = angular.module('loadFeed', []);

loadFeed.controller('feedController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.questions = [];

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?&order=desc&sort=votes&tagged=angular&site=stackoverflow'
}).then(function(feed) {

    console.log('success');
    console.log(feed);

    $scope.questions = feed.data.items;


},function(error) {
    console.log('error');
    console.log(error);
}); 

}]);
```

I want to update this in the {{question.title}}

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions" ng-show="!!questions.length" class="question-list">
    <h2>
    <a ng-href="{{question.link}}" title="{{question.title}}" target="_blank">{{question.title}}</a>
    </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**ng-bind-html**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive for binding content to an HTML element.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/96zhwtfo/)**

```js
angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('foo', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = "Can&#39;t bind to &#39;ngModel&#39; since it isn&#39;t a known property of &#39;input&#39;";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="foo">   
    <div ng-bind-html="title"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the help, this is working with the static '$scope.title = "Can&#39;t ...etc' ...however I can't get it to work with the '$scope.title = $scope.questions.title' - This returns empty

Although, '$scope.title = $scope.questions[0].title' does not show up empty, however obviously is only showing the specified object.

Am I missing something? I have tried to put it into an angular.forEach function but this repeats the title within the ng-bind-html="title"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ngBindHtml directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) for this, along with $sce and the trustAsHtml method.

Javascript:

```
(function(angular) {
      'use strict';
    var loadFeed = angular.module('loadFeed', []);

    loadFeed.controller('feedController', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', function($scope, $http, $sce) {

    $scope.questions = [];
    $scope.trustAsHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml;

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?&order=desc&sort=votes&tagged=angular&site=stackoverflow'
    }).then(function(feed) {

        console.log('success');
        console.log(feed);

        $scope.questions = feed.data.items;


    },function(error) {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(error);
    }); 

    }]);

    })(window.angular);
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ng-bind-html-production</title>


  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="loadFeed">
  <div ng-controller="feedController">
 <div ng-repeat="question in questions" ng-show="!!questions.length" class="question-list">
    <a ng-href="{{question.link}}" ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(question.title)" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

(Also updated the plunkr for your question)
See this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ea8xtqmQwiBJDZlYX5XF?p=preview) adapted from the example on the help page